# Node relative positioning does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, relative

I am trying to draw some boxes on a row, each one positioned relative to the previous one. With very little luck.
What am I doing wrong here ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, rectangle, pos=.5, align=center] (ClarkeBox)  { \tiny Clarke \\ \tiny transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of ClarkeBox, pos=.5, align=center] (ParkBox)  { \tiny Park \\ \tiny transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of ParkBox, fill=gray!25, pos=.5, align=center] (CtrlBox)  { \tiny Control \\ \tiny process};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of CtrlBox, pos=.5, align=center] (InvParkBox)  { \tiny Inverse \\ \tiny Park \\ \tiny transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of InvParkBox, pos=.5, align=center] (InvClarkeBox)  { \tiny Inverse \\ \tiny Clarke \\ \tiny transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, below=of CtrlBox, pos=.5, align=center] (RefBox)  { \tiny reference};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of InvClarkeBox, pos=.5, align=center] (ModulationBox)  { \tiny Output \\ \tiny Voltage \\ \tiny Modulation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pos key works for putting nodes on paths. You are placing directly.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The "pos=.5" is used to place the text inside the node in this example.

Comment: Try to remove `pos=.5`...

Comment: Aha. I stand duly corrected. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question here. 
Thanks to the comments above (from percusse and Paul Gaborit), and despite my misconception about the key `pos`, the whole think worked when I removed all of the `pos=.5`. I though that key was needed to properly place the text inside the node.

anyway, full code below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, rectangle, align=center] (ClarkeBox)  {  Clarke \\  transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of ClarkeBox,  align=center] (ParkBox)  {  Park \\  transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of ParkBox, fill=gray!25, align=center] (CtrlBox)  {  Control \\  process};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of CtrlBox, align=center] (InvParkBox)  {  Inverse \\  Park \\  transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of InvParkBox, align=center] (InvClarkeBox)  {  Inverse \\  Clarke \\  transform};
\node[draw, rectangle, below=of CtrlBox, align=center] (RefBox)  {  reference};
\node[draw, rectangle, right=of InvClarkeBox,  align=center] (ModulationBox)  {  Output \\  Voltage \\  Modulation};


\draw[red] ([shift={(0,0.25)}]ClarkeBox.west) --++ (-1,0)       node[left]{{\scriptsize  $i_U$}};
\draw[blue]  (ClarkeBox.west)--++ (-1,0)                        node[left]{{\scriptsize  $i_U$}};
\draw[green] ([shift={(0,-0.25)}]ClarkeBox.west) --++ (-1,0)    node[left]{{\scriptsize  $i_U$}};

\draw[violet] ([shift={(0,0.15)}]ClarkeBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,0.15)}]ParkBox.west) node[midway, above] (alpha1) {\scriptsize  $i_{\alpha}$};
\draw[orange] ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]ClarkeBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]ParkBox.west) node[midway, below] (beta1) {\scriptsize $i_{\beta}$};

\draw[violet] ([shift={(0,0.15)}]ParkBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,0.15)}]CtrlBox.west) node[midway, above] {\scriptsize  $i_q$};
\draw[orange] ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]ParkBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]CtrlBox.west) node[midway, below] {\scriptsize  $i_d$};

\draw[violet] ([shift={(0,0.15)}]CtrlBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,0.15)}]InvParkBox.west) node[midway, above] {\scriptsize  $i_q$};
\draw[orange] ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]CtrlBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]InvParkBox.west) node[midway, below] {\scriptsize  $i_d$};

\draw[violet] ([shift={(0,0.15)}]InvParkBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,0.15)}]InvClarkeBox.west) node[midway, above] {\scriptsize  $i_{\alpha}$};
\draw[orange] ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]InvParkBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,-0.15)}]InvClarkeBox.west) node[midway, below] {\scriptsize  $i_{\beta}$};

\draw[red] ([shift={(0,0.25)}]InvClarkeBox.east) -- ([shift={(0,0.25)}]ModulationBox.west);%  node[right] {\scriptsize $U$} ;
\draw[blue] ([shift={(0,0.0)}]InvClarkeBox.east)    -- ([shift={(0,0.0)}]ModulationBox.west);% node[right] {\scriptsize  $V$};
\draw[green] ([shift={(0,-0.25)}]InvClarkeBox.east)  -- ([shift={(0,-0.25)}]ModulationBox.west);% node[right] {\scriptsize  $W$};

\draw[-o,red] ([shift={(0,0.25)}]ModulationBox.east) --++ (1,0) node[right] {\scriptsize $v_U$} ;
\draw[-o,blue] ([shift={(0,0.0)}]ModulationBox.east)    --++ (1,0) node[right] {\scriptsize  $v_V$};
\draw[-o,green] ([shift={(0,-0.25)}]ModulationBox.east)  --++ (1,0) node[right] {\scriptsize  $v_W$};



\draw[dashed, gray] (ClarkeBox.north) --++ (0,1.5);
\draw[dashed, gray] (ParkBox.north) --++ (0,1.5);
\draw[dashed, gray] (CtrlBox.north) --++ (0,1.5);
\draw[dashed, gray] (InvClarkeBox.north) --++ (0,1.5);
\draw[dashed, gray] (InvParkBox.north) --++ (0,1.5);

\draw[violet, <-] ([shift={(-0.15,0)}]CtrlBox.south) --++ (0,-1) node[midway, left]{\scriptsize $ i_q^* $};
\draw[orange, <-] ([shift={(0.15,0)}]CtrlBox.south) --++ (0,-1) node[midway, right]{\scriptsize $ i_d^* $};



\begin{axis}[at={($(ClarkeBox.north west)+(-1cm,0.5cm)$)},trig format plots=rad,axis lines = middle,clip=false,xmax = 2.75*pi,ymax = 1.5,ymin = -0.5,y=0.4cm,x=0.12 cm]
    \addplot[color=red, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x)};% node [above right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_U$}; 
    \addplot[color=blue, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x+(2/3 * pi))};%  node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_V$};
    \addplot[color=green, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x-(2/3* pi))};% node [ right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_W$};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[at={($(ClarkeBox.north east)+(0cm,0.5cm)$)},trig format plots=rad,axis lines = middle,clip=false,xmax = 2.75*pi,ymax = 1.5,ymin = -0.5,y=0.4cm,x=0.12 cm]
    \addplot[color=violet, domain=0:2.4*pi,samples=200] {0.8*sin(x)};% node [above   right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_{\alpha}$};
    \addplot[color=orange, domain=0:2.4*pi,samples=200] {0.6*sin(x+(1/2 * pi))};% node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_{\beta}$};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[at={($(ParkBox.north east)+(0cm,0.5cm)$)},trig format plots=rad,axis lines = middle,clip=false,xmax = 34,ymax = 1.5,ymin = -0.5,y=0.4cm,x=0.1 cm]
    \addplot[color=violet, domain=0:17,samples=2] {0.8};% node [above    right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_q$};
    \addplot[color=violet, domain=17:34,samples=2] {1.1};% node [above   right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_q$};
    \draw[color=violet] (axis cs:17,0.8) -- (axis cs:17,1.1);
    \addplot[color=orange, domain=0:17,samples=2] {0.5};% node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_d$};
    \addplot[color=orange, domain=17:34,samples=2] {0.7};% node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_d$};
    \draw[color=orange] (axis cs:17,0.5) -- (axis cs:17,0.7);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[at={($(InvParkBox.north east)+(0cm,0.5cm)$)},trig format plots=rad,axis lines = middle,clip=false,xmax = 2.75*pi,ymax = 1.5,ymin = -0.5,y=0.4cm,x=0.12 cm]
    \addplot[color=violet, domain=0:2.4*pi,samples=200] {1.1*sin(x)};% node [above   right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_{\alpha}$};
    \addplot[color=orange, domain=0:2.4*pi,samples=200] {0.7*sin(x+(1/2 * pi))};% node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_{\beta}$};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[at={($(InvClarkeBox.north east)+(0cm,0.5cm)$)},trig format plots=rad,axis lines = middle,clip=false,xmax = 2.75*pi,ymax = 1.5,ymin = -0.5,y=0.4cm,x=0.12 cm]
\addplot[color=red, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x)};% node [above right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_U$}; 
\addplot[color=blue, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x+(2/3 * pi))};%  node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_V$};
\addplot[color=green, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x-(2/3* pi))};% node [ right, font=\scriptsize] {$i_W$};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[at={($(ModulationBox.north east)+(0cm,0.5cm)$)},trig format plots=rad,axis lines = middle,clip=false,xmax = 2.75*pi,ymax = 1.5,ymin = -0.5,y=0.4cm,x=0.12 cm]
    \addplot[->,color=red, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x) + (1/5)*sin(3*x)};% node [above right, font=\scriptsize] {$u_U$}; 
    \addplot[->,color=blue, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x+(2/3 * pi)) + (1/5)*sin(3*x)};%  node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$u_V$};
    \addplot[->,color=green, domain=0:2.25*pi,samples=200] {sin(x-(2/3* pi)) + (1/5)*sin(3*x)};% node [ right, font=\scriptsize] {$u_W$};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many compliments.

Comment: You may have looked at the manual already, but when you do something like `\draw (a) -- (b) node[pos=x]{...};`, the `pos` key determines where along the path from `a` to `b` the node is placed. With `pos=0` it is placed at `a`, with `pos=1` it is placed at `b`, and `0.5` is halfway between them.

Comment: I understand. First, i used `\draw[] (0.0) rectangle++ (2,2) node[pos=0.5] {Text}` to get the text centered inside the rectangle, but when I changed to `\node[rectangle]` it seems as if that part was no longer needed.